# What does 法令 mean in 法令紋 "smile lines, laugh lines"?

Tags: etymology

The 法令 in 法令紋 is confusing me.  法令 never shows up in the three morphemes in [NasoLabial Folds](https://tw.blog.voicetube.com/archives/35198/%E3%80%90%E7%94%9F%E6%B4%BB%E8%8B%B1%E6%96%87%E3%80%91%E6%B3%95%E4%BB%A4%E7%B4%8B%E3%80%81%E9%AD%9A%E5%B0%BE%E7%B4%8B%E3%80%81%E4%BA%BA%E9%AD%9A%E7%B7%9A%E8%A9%B2%E6%80%8E%E9%BA%BC%E8%AA%AA%EF%BC%9F/#2_%E6%B3%95%E4%BB%A4%E7%B4%8B_nasolabial_folds,_smile_lines,_laugh_lines)  broken down, and translated, into Chinese below.

> ### 2. 法令紋  nasolabial folds, smile lines, laugh lines
>
> nasal (adj.) 鼻子的 、 鼻音的
> labial (adj.) 嘴脣的
> fold (v.) 折 ; (n.) 摺痕
>
> 以後看到 naso- 這個字首的單字，都是跟鼻子有相關喔，因為法令紋是從鼻子延伸到唇邊，所以 nasolabial folds 就是法令紋的意思了。另一個比較簡單的說法是 smile lines 或 laugh lines，是因為很常開口大笑容易導致法令紋的出現。

[紋 means "  stripe; line; streak; figure; crack; wrinkle; pattern".](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%B4%8B)

But Collins Dictionary translates [法令](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/zh/dictionary/chinese-english/%E6%B3%95%E4%BB%A4) as "decree". How does 法令 mean NasoLabial? I feel like 法令 here means something else, or a metaphor?

Comment: I am not sure why "法令纹" is called like this. "法令" comes from "法" (law).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[法令紋](https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E6%B3%95%E4%BB%A4%E7%B4%8B/5947585)

> 名字由來

> 面相學上認為：鼻子兩側的皺紋可以反映一個人説話的分量，皺紋深的人説話大家都得聽，皺紋淺或者無皺紋的人説話沒人聽。這兩條皺紋深的人可以發號施令，所以叫法令線。又是我們説的八字紋。

> Origin of name

> According to physiognomy, the wrinkles on both sides of the nose can reflect the weight of a person's speech. People listen to someone who has these wrinkles, while people with shallow or no wrinkles are not heard.  People with deep lines beside the nose can issue **orders**, so they are called **decree** (法令) lines. It's also called the figure-of-eight lines.